# jquery direct function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates

i have this button inside a popup.(in a javascript file)

```
'<div class="thisdiv" >'+
    '<button class="btn btn-primary" >this</button>'+   
 '</div>'+
```

and i am accessing this in function

```
$('.thisdiv').on('click', function (e) {
       $('.overlay').hide();

        $('body').removeClass('overflow');

    });
```

this is basically supposed to be a button which, when clicked, closes the pop up. (the simple cross button)
but it does not work. it does not go into the function, i was told to use delegates. but shouldn't this be the simpler method? what am i missing?

Comment: are using jquery UI dialog box?

Comment: No, its associated to a 'more info button', when that button is clicked, an overlay appears, i want to add a button on that overlay. which when clicked, closes the over lay.

Comment: @Faizan, try `$(".thisdiv button").on("click")`. Your current function binds event to div and not children. Also I'd suggest to give a unique ID to button and do `$("#btnID").on("click")`. This will prevent the case when you add another button in same div and this function gets called on it.

Comment: thankyou for the tip, however the answer below the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are creating the elements dynamically. Then you need to use event delegation,

```
$(document).on('click', '.thisdiv', function (e) {
    $('.overlay').hide();
    $('body').removeClass('overflow');
});
```